# Mismatch in php version status vs php -v

Tags: drush, updating

I have multiple versions (7.2 and 7.4) on my ubuntu box and recently set the server to use 7.4 so that I could upgrade Drupal from 8.9 to 9.x.

Drupal reports/status shows my php version as 7.2, where as `php -v` and drush report the version as 7.4.

How ensure that Drupal sees the 7.4 version?

Comment: You know that you can have different versions on the CLI and for Apache.

Comment: @leymannx - yes, and i've enabled 7.4 and still seeing 7.2 listed in Drupal status

Comment: How did you "enable it"? @Jason

Comment: @NoSssweat - I used `sudo a2enmod php7.4` but i realized I `a2dismod` incorrectly. Once I used the correct `a2dismod`, then enabling worked correctly

Comment: Related https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296110/admin-ui-doesnt-see-the-correct-php-version